# JQuery Validation plugin on a <input> with a relaxed "step" attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I use jquery validation and I have a "number" input box with the step=10 set, even if the user should be allowed to manually set a value not multiple of 10 (e.g. 23):

```
<input name="myNumber" type="number" step=10 min=0>
```

In other words, I like Chrome and Firefox spins (up and down arrows) for stepping the number, as it increases the user's experience, but I don't like browser/jquery.validate rises an error if I manually set a value **not** multiple of the "step" (see picture below and the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gpcaretti/xpvt214o/860354/)).

[image]

Is there a way to have the input spin steps and, at the same time, relax the input constraint of to be multiple of the "step"?

For example (try the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpcaretti/xpvt214o/860354/)):

```
<input name="myNumber" type="number" step=10 min=0>
```

and

```
this.$form.validate({
    rules: {
        "myNumber": {
            required: true
            step: "relax"   // <<== example
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: CAn you create a fiddle instead ?

Comment: Added: http://jsfiddle.net/gpcaretti/xpvt214o/860354/

Comment: Why don't you create your custom input with increment and decrement signs

Comment: I agree, but my question is: is there a simple out-of-the-box way for having the desired behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect.  This is how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery Validate plugin is setting its `step` rule parameter based on the inline HTML attribute of `step="10"`.

If you don't want the validation rule to use the parameter from the HTML, just set your own.

```
rules: {
    "myNumber": {
        required: true,
        step: "1"  // <- this will over-ride parameter from HTML attribute
    }
}
```

All input values are valid, but yet the up/down arrows will move increments of 10

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/rcx9mztn/](http://jsfiddle.net/rcx9mztn/)**

Comment: it was so simple! Thank you!